# Solving an eigenvalue problem with "mixed" boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve the eigenvalue problem with "mixed" boundary conditions:
>
> $$\begin{cases}
>      X^{\prime\prime}(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0 \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0 < x < l\\
>      X(0) = X^{\prime}(l) = 0
>     \end{cases}$$
>   Here all the eigenvalues are strictly positive, so you may restrict yourself to a positive $\lambda$.

I normally don't post a question without somewhat of an attempt to answer it. But I am not sure how to proceed with this, a few hints and some suggestions should help me start it so that I can post an attempted solution to verify my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A second order, linear ODE such as

$X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0 \tag{1}$

has two linearly independent solutions for *fixed* $\lambda$, as is well-known.  It is also well-understood that such solutions may be represented as linear combinations of *exponential functions*; thus let us take the general solution to be of the form

$X(x) = c_1 e^{\mu_1 x} + c_2 e^{\mu_2 x}, \tag{2}$

where we allow $c_1, c_2, \mu_1, \mu_2 \in \Bbb C$.

Then

$X'(x) = c_1 \mu_1 e^{\mu_1 x } + c_2 \mu_2 e^{\mu_2 x}, \tag{3}$

and

$X''(x) = c_1 \mu_1^2 e^{\mu_1 x} + c_2 \mu_2^2 e^{\mu_2 x}; \tag{4}$

Substituting (2) and (4) into (1) yields

$c_1(\mu_1^2 + \lambda)e^{\mu_1 x} + c_2(\mu_2^2 + \lambda)e^{\mu_2 x} = 0; \tag{5}$

the boundary condition at $0$, $X(0) = 0$, tells us

$c_1 + c_2 = X(0) = 0, \tag{6}$

whence

$c_2 = -c_1; \tag{7}$

the boundary condition at $x = l$, $X'(l) = 0$, in concert with (7), indicates that

$c_1 \mu_1 e^{\mu_1 l } - c_1 \mu_2 e^{\mu_2 l} = 0. \tag{8}$

We further  conclude *via* (7) that we must have

$c_1 \ne 0, \tag{9}$

since otherwise the entire solution (2) trivializes to $X(x) = 0$; we may thus cancel $c_1$ out of (8), gaining

$\mu_1 e^{\mu_1 l } = \mu_2 e^{\mu_2 l}. \tag{10}$

Turning briefly to (5), we conclude from the linear independence of $e^{\mu_1x}$, $e^{\mu_2 x}$ that

$c_1(\mu_1^2 + \lambda) = 0 = c_2(\mu_2^2 + \lambda); \tag{11}$

by (7) and (9),

$\mu_1^2 + \lambda = 0 = \mu_2^2 + \lambda, \tag{12}$

that is,

$\mu_1^2 = \mu_2^2 = - \lambda; \tag{13}$

with $\lambda > 0$ we conclude that

$\mu_1, \mu_2 \in \{i\sqrt \lambda, -i \sqrt \lambda \}; \tag{14}$

since we require that $e^{\mu_1x}$ and $e^{\mu_2x}$ be linearly independent, we may take

$\mu_1 = i\sqrt \lambda; \mu_2 = - i\sqrt \lambda. \tag{15}$

We insert (15) into (10):

$i\sqrt \lambda e^{i\sqrt \lambda l} = -i\sqrt \lambda e^{-i\sqrt \lambda l}, \tag{16}$

or

$e^{2i\sqrt \lambda l} = -1; \tag{17}$

from (17) we may infer

$2\sqrt \lambda l = (2n + 1)\pi \tag{18}$

where $N \in \Bbb Z$;

thus we may set

$\lambda_n = (n + \dfrac{1}{2})^2 \dfrac{\pi^2}{l^2}. \tag{19}$

We may also define

$\nu_n = (n + \dfrac{1}{2}) \dfrac{\pi}{l}.  \tag{20}$

If we pull everything together we can find the eigenfuctions as well.  Using (2), (7), (15) and (20) in concert, we see that the eigenfunction corresponding to $n \in \Bbb Z$ is

$X_n(x) = c_1 e^{i \nu_n x} - c_1 e^{-i \nu_n x} = c_1(e^{i \nu_n x} - e^{-i\nu_n x})$
$= c_1 (2 i \sin \nu_n x) = 2ic_1 \sin ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})x; \tag{21}$

we are free to choose the constant $c_1$ as we please; taking

$c_1 = -\dfrac{i}{2}, \tag{22}$

we obtain the conventionally normalized eigenfunctions

$X_n(x) = \sin ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})x. \tag{23}$

We check:

$X_n(0) = \sin 0 = 0, \tag{24}$

$X'_n(l) = ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})\cos ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})l = ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l}) \cos ((n + \dfrac{1}{2}) \pi = 0; \tag{25}$

also,

$X'_n(x) = ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})\cos ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})x; \tag{26}$

$X''_n(x) = -((n + \dfrac{1}{2})^2\dfrac{\pi^2}{l^2})\sin ((n + \dfrac{1}{2})\dfrac{\pi}{l})x = -\lambda_n X_n(x), \tag{27}$

where $\lambda_n$ is given by (19); thus,

$X''_n(x) + \lambda_n X_n(x) = 0, \tag{28}$

as required.

Comment: From (12) and (13) I am a little confused, can we not cancel out the $\lambda$?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer by the way. I was wondering if you knew if I am doing anything wrong here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321479/solving-the-wave-equation-with-neumann-like-boudary-conditions

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that satisfy the ODE and
$$
                  X(0)=0,\;\; X'(0)=1,
$$
are
$$
                  X_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
The case where $\lambda=0$ is the limiting case as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, which is $X_{0}(x)=x$. The $\lambda$ for which the full eigenvalue problem has a solution are those for which
$$
          0 = X_{\lambda}'(l) = \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}l).
$$
$\lambda=0$ does not lead to a solution. The $\lambda$ that work are
$$
              \sqrt{\lambda}l = (n+1/2)\pi,\;\; n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\cdots \\
                    \lambda_n = \frac{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}{l^2},\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding distinct eigenfunctions are, up to constant multipliers,
$$
   X_n(x)=\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/l),\;\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Comment: I don't understand your solution, the boundary conditions are $X(0) = X'(l) = 0$

Comment: I'm with Wolfgang on this!

Comment: @Wolfgang : $X_n(0)=0$. $X_n'(l)=(n+1/2)\pi/l \cos((n+1/2)\pi l/l)=(n+1/2)\pi/l\cos((n+1/2)\pi)=0$.

Comment: I see, but you state that $X(0) = 0$ (I agree with that) But you state that $X'(0) = 1$ How do you know that initially?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 : Any eigenfunction will be a constant multiple of the solution where $X(0)=0,\; X'(0)=1$. This normalizes everything so that $X_{\lambda}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^n f_n(x)$ is an entire function of $\lambda$. Then special cases such as $\lambda=0$ become limits in $\lambda$ of the functions for $\lambda\ne 0$, e.g. $x=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ is $X_0(x)$. And it makes the eigenvalues the zeros of an entire function of $\lambda$. I've learned this normalization over time in order to avoid special cases.